# helperSkipTransparentExpressionWrappers.skipTransparentExprWrapperNodes is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs, es6-modules

I've tried upgrading jest from 27 to 28. This is on a react library. On all of my tests, I'm getting back `helperSkipTransparentExpressionWrappers.skipTransparentExprWrapperNodes is not a function` and the tests are failing to run.

This seems to be happening at `node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining/src/transform.ts`

I can see that `plugin-proposal-optional-chaining` is installed at 7.21.0, and `@babel/helper-skip-transparent-expression-wrappers` is in my node_modules with version 7.20.0, and `skipTransparentExprWrapperNodes` is defined as an export from that module. @babel/preset-env is installed at 7.20.2, and in node_modules, it's getting plugin-proposal-optional-chaining at 7.18.9, so maybe that's the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this line to devDependencies fixed it for me:

```
"@babel/helper-skip-transparent-expression-wrappers": "7.20.0",
```

7.21.0 also seems to work.

Without it 7.22.5 is installed for me with which I have the same error that you have.